# Timer is different than the proper time

Tags: jquery

I have a time difference between the actual time of a listing and the time shown by the timer code.
So, for a listing, this code show the remaining time as 8d 18h 23m 58s GTB Standard Time instead of the real one of 9d, 1h, 23m, 45s.

Can anyone pinpoint why this happens and also if there is any solution to fix it (or at least stop it to show the text GTB Standard Time, so just the actual time). Thank you

```
function timelefttolistnewtimer(){

var arr = [];
var offset = getTimezoneName();

jQuery('.timelefttolistnewtimer').each(function(k,v) {
    
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    
    
    arr["countDownDate"+id] = new Date(jQuery(this).data('time')).getTime();
    

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    arr["x"+id] = setInterval(function() {

      // Get today's date and time
      arr["now"+id]= new Date().getTime();
        
      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      arr["distance"+id] = arr["countDownDate"+id]- arr["now"+id];
        
      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      arr["days"+id] = Math.floor(arr["distance"+id] / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      arr["hours"+id] = Math.floor((arr["distance"+id] % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      arr["minutes"+id] = Math.floor((arr["distance"+id] % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      arr["seconds"+id] = Math.floor((arr["distance"+id] % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      jQuery("#"+id).html(arr["days"+id] + "d " + arr["hours"+id] + "h "
      + arr["minutes"+id] + "m " + arr["seconds"+id] + "s " + offset);
    
      console.log('arr');
        console.log(arr["seconds"+id]);
        console.log(offset);
        
      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (arr["distance"+id] < 0) {
        clearInterval(arr["x"+id]);
        jQuery("#"+id).html("EXPIRED");
      }
    }, 1000);


});
```

}

```
function timelefttolistnewtimer1(){

var arr = [];
var offset = getTimezoneName();

jQuery('.timelefttolistnewtimer1').each(function(k,v) {
    
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    
    
    arr["countDownDate"+id] = new Date(jQuery(this).data('time')).getTime();
    

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    arr["x"+id] = setInterval(function() {

      // Get today's date and time
      arr["now"+id]= new Date().getTime();
        
      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      arr["distance"+id] = arr["countDownDate"+id]- arr["now"+id];
        
      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      arr["days"+id] = Math.floor(arr["distance"+id] / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      arr["hours"+id] = Math.floor((arr["distance"+id] % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      arr["minutes"+id] = Math.floor((arr["distance"+id] % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      arr["seconds"+id] = Math.floor((arr["distance"+id] % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
     

      jQuery("#"+id).html(arr["days"+id] + "d " + arr["hours"+id] + "h "
      + arr["minutes"+id] + "m " + arr["seconds"+id] + "s " + offset);


      //console.log('arr');
        //console.log(arr["seconds"+id]);
        //console.log(offset);
        
      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (arr["distance"+id] < 0) {
        clearInterval(arr["x"+id]);
        jQuery("#"+id).html("EXPIRED");
      }
    }, 1000);


});
```

}

```
function getTimezoneName() {
var timeSummer = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
var summerOffset = -1 * timeSummer.getTimezoneOffset();
var timeWinter = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
var winterOffset = -1 * timeWinter.getTimezoneOffset();
var timeZoneHiddenField;

if (-720 == summerOffset && -720 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Dateline Standard Time'; }
else if (-660 == summerOffset && -660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'UTC-11'; }
else if (-660 == summerOffset && -660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Samoa Standard Time'; }
else if (-660 == summerOffset && -600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Hawaiian Standard Time'; }
else if (-570 == summerOffset && -570 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField.value = 'Pacific/Marquesas'; }
//                else if (-540 == summerOffset && -600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField.value = 'America/Adak'; }
//                else if (-540 == summerOffset && -540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField.value = 'Pacific/Gambier'; }
else if (-480 == summerOffset && -540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Alaskan Standard Time'; }
//                else if (-480 == summerOffset && -480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Pitcairn'; }
else if (-420 == summerOffset && -480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific Standard Time'; }
else if (-420 == summerOffset && -420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'US Mountain Standard Time'; }
else if (-360 == summerOffset && -420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Mountain Standard Time'; }
else if (-360 == summerOffset && -360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central America Standard Time'; }
//                else if (-360 == summerOffset && -300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Easter'; }
else if (-300 == summerOffset && -360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Standard Time'; }
else if (-300 == summerOffset && -300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SA Pacific Standard Time'; }
else if (-240 == summerOffset && -300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Eastern Standard Time'; }
else if (-270 == summerOffset && -270 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Venezuela Standard Time'; }
else if (-240 == summerOffset && -240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SA Western Standard Time'; }
else if (-240 == summerOffset && -180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Brazilian Standard Time'; }
else if (-180 == summerOffset && -240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Atlantic Standard Time'; }
else if (-180 == summerOffset && -180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Montevideo Standard Time'; }
else if (-180 == summerOffset && -120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'E. South America Standard Time'; }
else if (-150 == summerOffset && -210 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Mid-Atlantic Standard Time'; }
else if (-120 == summerOffset && -180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'America/Godthab'; }
else if (-120 == summerOffset && -120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SA Eastern Standard Time'; }
else if (-60 == summerOffset && -60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Cape Verde Standard Time'; }
else if (0 == summerOffset && -60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Azores Daylight Time'; }
else if (0 == summerOffset && 0 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Morocco Standard Time'; }
else if (60 == summerOffset && 0 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'GMT Standard Time'; }
else if (60 == summerOffset && 60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Africa/Algiers'; }
else if (60 == summerOffset && 120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Namibia Standard Time'; }
else if (120 == summerOffset && 60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central European Standard Time'; }
else if (120 == summerOffset && 120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'South Africa Standard Time'; }
else if (180 == summerOffset && 120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'GTB Standard Time'; }
else if (180 == summerOffset && 180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'E. Africa Standard Time'; }
else if (240 == summerOffset && 180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Russian Standard Time'; }
else if (240 == summerOffset && 240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Arabian Standard Time'; }
else if (270 == summerOffset && 210 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Iran Standard Time'; }
else if (270 == summerOffset && 270 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Afghanistan Standard Time'; }
else if (300 == summerOffset && 240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pakistan Standard Time'; }
else if (300 == summerOffset && 300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'West Asia Standard Time'; }
else if (330 == summerOffset && 330 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Indian Standard Time'; }
else if (345 == summerOffset && 345 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Nepal Standard Time'; }
else if (360 == summerOffset && 300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'N. Central Asia Standard Time'; }
else if (360 == summerOffset && 360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Asia Standard Time'; }
else if (390 == summerOffset && 390 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Myanmar Standard Time'; }
else if (420 == summerOffset && 360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'North Asia Standard Time'; }
else if (420 == summerOffset && 420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SE Asia Standard Time'; }
else if (480 == summerOffset && 420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'North Asia East Standard Time'; }
else if (480 == summerOffset && 480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'China Standard Time'; }
else if (540 == summerOffset && 480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Yakutsk Standard Time'; }
else if (540 == summerOffset && 540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Tokyo Standard Time'; }
else if (570 == summerOffset && 570 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Cen. Australia Standard Time'; }
else if (570 == summerOffset && 630 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Australia/Adelaide'; }
else if (600 == summerOffset && 540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Asia/Yakutsk'; }
else if (600 == summerOffset && 600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'E. Australia Standard Time'; }
else if (600 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'; }
else if (630 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Australia/Lord_Howe'; }
else if (660 == summerOffset && 600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Tasmania Standard Time'; }
else if (660 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'West Pacific Standard Time'; }
else if (690 == summerOffset && 690 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Pacific Standard Time'; }
else if (720 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Magadan Standard Time'; }
else if (720 == summerOffset && 720 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Fiji Standard Time'; }
else if (720 == summerOffset && 780 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'New Zealand Standard Time'; }
else if (765 == summerOffset && 825 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Chatham'; }
else if (780 == summerOffset && 780 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Tonga Standard Time'; }
else if (840 == summerOffset && 840 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Kiritimati'; }
else { timeZoneHiddenField = 'US/Pacific'; }
return timeZoneHiddenField;
```

}

The code get's split wrong by stackoverflow, that's why i add it in 3 sections.

Comment: I see that i can remove the value like GTB Standard Time and then the countdown will not show it. Remains the time difference to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You pass the arguments from the loop to the interval function.

You should know that the variables in the next loop are different, and the interval function does not know the variables in the loop. So you have to add them to the call of the interval function so that when you call the interval function later, you have the arguments to work with.

Just a function as an example for you:

```
function timelefttolistnewtimer1() {

    var arr = [];
    var offset = getTimezoneName();

    jQuery('.timelefttolistnewtimer1').each(function (k, v) {

        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        arr["countDownDate" + id] = Date.parse(jQuery(this).data('time'));


        // Update the count down every 1 second
        arr["x" + id] = setInterval(function (id2, offset2) { // move forward the params for use them in the interval function #tipp1

            // Get today's date and time
            arr["now" + id2] = Date.parse(new Date());

            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            arr["distance" + id2] = arr["countDownDate" + id2] - arr["now" + id2];

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds

            arr["seconds" + id2] = Math.floor((arr["distance" + id2] / 1000) % 60);
            arr["minutes" + id2] = Math.floor((arr["distance" + id2] / 1000 / 60) % 60);
            arr["hours" + id2] = Math.floor((arr["distance" + id2] / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            arr["days" + id2] = Math.floor(arr["distance" + id2] / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

            // Output the result in an element with id2="demo"


            jQuery("#" + id2).html(arr["days" + id2] + "d " + arr["hours" + id2] + "h "
                + arr["minutes" + id2] + "m " + arr["seconds" + id2] + "s " + offset2);


            //console.log('arr');
            //console.log(arr["seconds"+id2]);
            //console.log(offset);

            // If the count down is over, write some text 
            if (arr["distance" + id2] < 0) {
                clearInterval(arr["x" + id2]);
                jQuery("#" + id2).html("EXPIRED");
            }
        }, 1000, id, offset); // move forward the origin variables to use them in the interval function #tipp2 (function arguments id2, offset2)


    });
}
```

Also, the `arr` object should be globally available in case the function `timelefttolistnewtimer1` is called multiple times. The question is whether these need to be saved at all?

Comment: I tried the code and the real time shows as 2d, 3h while the timer shows 1d 21h 53m 18s so there is still the big difference.

Comment: I have updated my code that is causing the problems. So it shouldn't be a problem now. I'm not 100% sure, because I don't have an example and I just skimmed over it quickly.

Comment: Still no luck, almost 6 hours apart.

Comment: Can you please provide me the timestamp that is used? It sounds for me your timestamp is crap any that this makes problems.

Comment: I updated the code a second time, and use `Date.parse(xxx)`

Comment: 2d, 3h, 24m, 54s this is the real clock now and the end date shows as Nov 7 2021 8:34:00 AM EST. This end date is coming from php and in timer code from the thread was added to a different page via that code and like i said, the times do not match. Right now the timer that shows wrong, shows 1d 21h 22m 8s GTB Standard Time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238900/discussion-between-jomaar-and-adyyda).